# How can I hide taskbar labels in Windows 10 without combining icons?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible to hide taskbar labels in Windows 10 *without combining icons*?

So visually I'm looking for something like this:

[image: No text labels in taskbar icons]

Solutions that don't require additional apps or software installs are preferred.

Comment: Picture? Please?

Comment: @Ramhound check the edit

Comment: Have you tried [the hack that worked on Windows 7 and 8](http://superuser.com/a/431087/194694)? (you should probably use 48 instead of 56)

Comment: @gronostaj Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Then I guess we have to wait until [7+TT](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) is ported to Windows 10. You can chip in [here](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-and-windows-10).

Comment: Or to pray at [microsoft.uservoice](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6787389-taskbar-buttons-never-combine-hide-labels)...

Comment: Taskbar Settings > Combine Taskbar drop down > Hide labels https://superuser.com/questions/947070/how-can-i-hide-taskbar-labels-in-windows-10-without-combining-icons

Comment: @stevedude That doesn't exist...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) can do that. Just check *Don't combine grouped buttons* in *Combining* section.

[image: Screenshot of decombined buttons]

It works with Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10. The author adds support for new Windows releases very quickly - they're either already supported on release or within a few days.

Comment: While this solution isn't optimal, I'm marking it as accepted since its so far the only way so far.

Comment: Any registry tweaks for this instead?

Comment: @Maelish No, at least we're not aware of any. `MinWidth` hack that worked on Windows 7...8.1 does nothing on Win10.

Comment: 7+ Taskbar Tweajer is really awesome. If you like to configure a lot, then probably even more so. However, each new Windows release breaks it, unfortunately. I think it's a trade off...

Comment: @bytecode77 yeah, the latest update broke it again. It's like MS goal was to prevent this functionality at all cost, braking it purposely with each release but adding a bazillion of other useless "features" and settings.

Comment: Installed RS4 today, too. Yeah. They don't want to include too many options so Windows remains "easy and slim".

Comment: @t3chb0t Most likely it's not intentional. 7+TT works by patching explorer.exe in memory, but memory layout can change when any changes are made, even when they aren't related to the taskbar.

Answer (score 16):

In order to do this, simply set your taskbar setting to "Always combine, hide labels".  Then, download [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) and under "Combining" choose "Don't combine grouped buttons".

You will effectively get: "Never combine, hide labels".  Hope this helps.

Comment: this answer is more complete than the accepted one

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, which explicitly states that he does NOT want to combine icons.

Comment: @dynamichael 7+TT overrides the Windows setting. This will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, one may also use "Do not group" instead of "Do not combine" in order to have more freedom dealing with the icons.

Answer (score 6):

***This is an old question**, however as Win 10 is still missing this option, I'm  willing to leave this answer here:*

1. Under taskbar settings, choose "Always, hide labels"
2. Use one of the following options to disable taskbar combining:

**option1: edit the registry**

- Go to the following Registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

- On the right, create a new **32-Bit DWORD** value *NoTaskGrouping*
- Set its value data to 1 in decimals
- Restart Windows 10

**option2: edit group policy editor**

- Launch the Group Policy Editor app (***gpedit.msc***)
- Set the option "*User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Start Menu and Taskbar \ Prevent grouping of taskbar items*" to **Enabled**

For more illustrations you could check this link: https://winaero.com/disable-taskbar-button-combining-windows-10/

Regards,

Bishoy

Comment: option2 worked for me, but required a reboot. It had the side-effect of making all buttons become the "stretched" version where I see an icon and a text label. Previously, my main monitor had small buttons (no text) and my secondary monitor had stretched buttons. I have no idea why it was like that before, or why this setting changed it.

Comment: Well it seems the ultimate solution includes editing to "explorer.exe" which is accomplished by using "7+ taskbar tweaker" for example, I can find also a detailed explanation in this link:

https://gist.github.com/blole/428d67218642379489fe

which instructs to change this instruction "explorer.exe+575ED - BB 01000000           - mov ebx,00000001" to be "explorer.exe+575ED - BB 02000000           - mov ebx,00000002" .. But it seems to be so sophisticated for me.

Comment: Neither option 1 nor 2 results in the labels being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I have preferred the Never Combine and Hide Labels for window buttons myself.

But, what I have just discovered is that the more windows that are opened, the button size and amount of label text gets reduced.

I just tried that. I have opened right now 30 windows.  The button is reduced to the normal size it would have with no labels.  Hovering the pointer over a window button displays a menu with all the page titles opened in the web browser.

Comment: How is this useful? Are you proposing opening a bunch of unnecessary windows just to hide the labels?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get it done. Works even where [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) doesn't work (e.g., on custom Windows 10 deployments).

When I use the "never combine" option, the text does hide when the task bar is getting full.  So I just keep the taskbar full at all times, by keeping a number of Notepad instances running. Looks like this:

[image: screenshot1]

Even though it needs additional clicks, at least it works and helps when working with multiple documents. I just click in additional instances (from a toolbar on the right) or close them whenever the number of running apps changes.

I tried it with Notepad, but if anyone knows an .exe app that has a completely transparent (or minimal) icon and can be used like this, or a way to automate this to avoid clicks, please share. I tried notepad2 but modifying its .exe with ResourceHacker breaks the app. With a transparent app, it would look something like this:

[image: screenshot2]

EDIT: My cousin made an "empty app" and all it does is run an empty app whose icon is just a dot, so it looks almost exactly as envisioned. U will need to run it multiple times to fill the taskbar. I've shared it zipped [here](http://www.swiftstrategy.pl/lib/ffxvij/Emptyapp-jm4jjk4j.zip). In case of concerns, do perform a virus scan.

Comment: This is an awful solution. How can you possibly live with this

Comment: Can't disagree... So why not just get used to living with variable active icon width with default "never combine" option on Win setups that don't allow 7+ taskbar tweaker? Depends on how much this bugs you and what options you have. This helped me switch to the default windows setting at the end... instead of reinventing Windows. Yet it was fun nevertheless... Enjoy!

Comment: I don't see how this is useful if there are solutions that don't require cluttering your taskbar (and Alt-Tab) with garbage windows.

Comment: There are custom Windows 10 builds locked by admins where u can not use those solutions, can't install 7+tt, can't regedit, where the "never combine" still doesn't keep width so... So Indeed a niche solution. Be glad u dont have to live with that! For me it was a nice transition from 7+tt to the vanilla windows "never combine". Its interesting how ppl are challenging this part of the problem. Having transitioned to what windows offers now i should start wondering- isnt this whole thread an exaggeration? Thanks for the inspiring downvotes, having reflected ill mark the thread as redundant.

Answer (score -5):

1. unlock toolbar
2. only then, a new menu will be shown when you right-click over an icon
3. uncheck the 'show text' option
4. lock toolbar
5. thank me later :)

Comment: I think the question was asking how to hide the text for all taskbar items automatically.

Comment: Where is this hidden menu? Could you add a screenshot?