# How do I remove titles from Windows 10 taskbar and keep icons only

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons, windows-10

In my Windows 10 Pro I got icons and titles on taskbar. But I want to have icons only (like at the bottom on the picture).

Is there an option for this?

How do I remove titles from Windows 10 taskbar and keep icons only?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate, but no answer has been upvoted/marked: http://superuser.com/questions/947070/how-can-i-hide-taskbar-labels-in-windows-10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is my answer from a [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/947070/how-can-i-hide-taskbar-labels-in-windows-10) but no answer from that question has been upvoted or marked at the time of writing this so it cannot be chosen as a potential duplicate.

Right click on the taskbar and select **Properties**. Where it says **Taskbar buttons**, you want to set it to **Always combine, hide labels**.

[image: Properties]

Result:

[image: Taskbar]

Comment: sure would be nice if they offered "Combine when full, hide labels". Since hiding the labels makes combining less necessary. Their option makes no sense to me.

Comment: On newer windows, right click taskbar -> settings -> taskbar -> combine taskbar buttons -> always hide, hide labels

Comment: You might not expect it but when it shows them as icons and combines them it won't show badges even when "show badges" option is enabled. Badges only work when the labels are visible and when nothing is combined, for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10:
Right click taskbar -> choose Taskbar settings.

Make sure the left menu option highlights "Taskbar". 
Find "Show badges on taskbar buttons". Turn it to off.

In addition select from the "Combine taskbar buttons" drop down the "Always hide labels" option.

You now only have icons on the task bar.

Comment: What I want that they won't let me do is to see the badges and the icons but not see labels.  The ONLY way to hide labels is to combine the icons, which also, regardless of the other options won't show notification badges.

Comment: This doesn't work.