# How can I hide taskbar labels in Windows 10 without combining icons (2020)?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Is it possible to hide taskbar labels in Windows 10 *without combining icons*?

So visually I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Solutions that don't require additional apps or software installs are preferred.

Comment: Small Icons show Task Bar icons without labels. If you then want to hide such icons, unpin them from the Task Bar.  This end of the Task Bar (left end) is different from the System Tray which has a different method of hiding icons

Comment: @John Unfortunately even while using the small icons the labels are still appearing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I checked my own settings on 3 machines here where I do not see labels, and unfortunately, this must be achieved by combining icons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide taskbar labels in Windows 10 without combining icons?](https://superuser.com/questions/947070/how-can-i-hide-taskbar-labels-in-windows-10-without-combining-icons)

Answer (score 2):

Following [this](https://superuser.com/a/831516/302676) similar answer and testing on a Windows 10 May update release VM, I can confirm this works - even though it seems it's for Windows 7, it works nicely on my 10 VM. I only tested with Word and Explorer, but its worth trying out.

The program is called 7+ Taskbar Tweaker, but I strongly recommend you go to the link hyperlinked above for the full answer and instructions on doing so.

Image of it working on my machine:

[image]

Comment: __Solutions that don't require additional apps or software installs are preferred__

Comment: @vssher I am aware of that, but since I could not find a native setting for this, the next best thing in my opinion is a lightweight utility that makes it as seamless as it would be if it were native - OP doesn't have to accept my answer but it is an option if they want to go that route.

Comment: Hey QuickishFM, thanks for the answer. I tried it but it appears to not be working with the current version of Windows. I updated it around the end of december.

Comment: @GrandiosoDuck hmm, I'm not too sure then, sorry. Was the Windows setting still as "always, hide labels"?

Comment: @GrandiosoDuck didn't you want them to not group?

Comment: Sorry, i meant "it just doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

1. Under taskbar settings, choose "Always, hide labels"
2. Use one of the following options to disable taskbar combining:

**option1: edit the registry**

- Go to the following Registry key:
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
- On the right, create a new **32-Bit DWORD** value *NoTaskGrouping*
- Set its value data to 1 in decimals
- Restart Windows 10

**option2: edit group policy editor**

- Launch the Group Policy Editor app (gpedit.msc)
- Set the option "*User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Start Menu and Taskbar \ Prevent grouping of taskbar items*" to **Enabled**

For more illustrations you could check this link:
https://winaero.com/disable-taskbar-button-combining-windows-10/

Regards,

Bishoy

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, which means they should include everything that's needed to answer the question. Your answer relies on an external link which can go bad or change its content anytime. Please include essential parts of the linked page in your answer (use the [Edit] button). Keep the original link for attribution.

Comment: Edited the answer ...