# How do you disable the hover over labels on the Windows (10) Taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I often use a program (Adobe Illustrator) that has a navigation menu at the bottom of the screen (just above the Windows taskbar). When using the program's navigation buttons it is very easy to activate the hover over descriptions of the Windows taskbar, in fact I don't think you actually need to make contact with the taskbar, just be slightly above it.

This has the rather annoying effect of showing the hover label over the navigation menu of the program I'm trying to use.

Is there a way I can completely disable these hover over labels with the caveat that I don't want to automatically hide the taskbar? Please see the image below which shows the label in question.

[image: Taskbar Hover Label Example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons). See the Windows 10 answer

Comment: Alternatively you can always move the taskbar itself to the top or sides, or not set illustrator as maximised but resize it so that there is a 5 pixel gap at the bottom.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thanks. I already have "Combine taskbar buttons" set to "Always hide labels". It still shows the hover over labels with the other settings. I just tried the W10 fix mentioned through the Group Policy Editor (as the registry \Explorer key was missing) and that didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you. I'll keep these in mind as fall backs as they're more like workarounds than a fixes. I'm stubborn and won't move the taskbar elsewhere!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://tweaker.rammichael.com/) to the rescue.

[image: Screenshot of 7+ Taskbar Tweaker window]

In the *Hovering* group (left column, 4th group) select *Nothing*.

7+TT will keep running hidden behind an icon in the notification area. It consumer very little resources - barely any at all.

It's also very stable. Once a new Windows version is released it may gracefully stop working for a few days without breaking anything, but it will self-update once support for the new version is added. But honestly this was more of a (very minor) problem a few years ago. Recently new Windows 10 releases are supported as soon as they are available to the users.

Comment: Perfect! The does exactly what I need. I tried to check if the program modified some specific Windows key in the registry but no luck with that. I guess I'll be adding this to my list of things to include on new installations. Thank you.

Comment: @0gits It's patching the `explorer.exe` process in memory. Most of 7+TT features are not available through registry modifications. I believe _"Don't combine grouped buttons"_ is [the most popular one](https://superuser.com/q/947070/194694).